# Passing Array to jQuery Selector

Tags: jquery, arrays, selector

I believe it's possible to pass an array of DOM objects to jQuery's selector so you can manipulate multiple objects at the same time. I've tried doing this as follows but can't get it to work for some reason...

```
$(Sel).animate({
        backgroundColor: "#FF0000"
    }, 250, 'linear', function() {

        $(this).animate({
            backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF"
        }, 250, 'linear');

    });
```

Is it actually possible to do this or am I barking up the wrong tree?

I've put together [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PottyMonster/AX3C8/) to test things out. The aim is to make a booking system where slots of half hour are selected so I need to manipulate "this" and the cell below on the next row.

Any advice greatly appreciated.

Code from fiddle:

```
function HighlightCells() {

    $('table#Calendar tbody tr td:not(".TimeCell")').live('mouseenter', function() {
        var Sel = new Array();
        Sel[1] = $(this);

        // Count number of previous TDs. Resut is base 0
        var NumIn = $(this).prevAll('td').length;

        // Increment count to compensate for nth-child being base 1
        NumIn++;

        var NextRow = $(this).closest('tr').next('tr');

        Sel[2] = $(NextRow).children("td:nth-child(" + NumIn + ")");

        // Animate the cell background colour red to white
        $(Sel).animate({
            backgroundColor: "#FF0000"
        }, 250, 'linear', function() {

            $(this).animate({
                backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF"
            }, 250, 'linear');

        });


        $('table#Calendar tbody td').live('mouseleave', function() {
            $(this).text("");
        });

    });

}

HighlightCells();
```

Comment: [According to the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1), it is possible: *"`jQuery (elementArray)` : An array containing a set of DOM elements to wrap in a jQuery object."* What is `Sel`? *edit:* nvm, didn't have a look at the fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this

```
var Sel = new Array();
Sel[1] = this;
```

and

```
Sel[2] = NextRow.children("td:nth-child(" + NumIn + ")")[0]; 
//  retrieves the DOM element  
// Also no need to wrap NextRow with $() since it's already a jQuery object
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wirey00/AX3C8/27/

Answer (score 3):

You are making a jQuery object from an array of jQuery objects.  You can't do that, it doesn't work.

You need to either make `Sel` an array of DOM elements (note: arrays are zero-indexed, so `Sel[1]` is actually the 2nd element, but when building arrays, use `.push` unless you *really* need to use the actual keys):

```
var Sel = [];  // this is preferred over `new Array()`
Sel.push($(this).get(0)); // or Sel.push(this)
// ...
Sel.push($(NextRow).children("td:nth-child(" + NumIn + ")").get(0));
```

Or make `Sel` a jQuery object to begin with, and then add elements into it.

```
var Sel = $();
Sel = Sel.add(this);
// ...
Sel = Sel.add($(NextRow).children("td:nth-child(" + NumIn + ")"));
// ...
Sel.animate({ // sel is already a jQuery object, so we don't need `$(Sel)`
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using an array of jQuery objects. Instead, you need an array of DOM objects.

```
var Sel = new Array();
        Sel[1] = this;
```

and

```
Sel[2] = $(NextRow).children("td:nth-child(" + NumIn + ")").get();
```

though, shouldn't that be `Sel[0] = this` and `Sel[1] = ...`?

Comment: Don't you mean `var Sel = new Array;`?

Comment: Yes, that's a typo in the fiddle.

Comment: @Rocket Don't you mean `var Sel = ["why is this sparse", this]` :P